# How to get value from textBox by its name?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, textbox, controls

I am trying to get value from textBox by its name using Control class?
**There is my code:**

`Control ctl = FindControl(this, "B1");
      if (ctl is TextBox)
        listBox1.Items.Add(((TextBox)ctl).Text);`
//"B1" - it's textBox name

```
public static Control FindControl(Control parent, string ctlName)
    {
        foreach (Control ctl in parent.Controls)
        {
            if (ctl.Name.Equals(ctlName))
            {
                return ctl;
            }

            FindControl(ctl, ctlName);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The problem is that the compiler does not go into the function.
What could be the problem?

Comment: what language and envirnoment are you using?

Comment: C# in Visual Studio 2010

Comment: add the c# tag to your question , so people can answer your question better

Comment: Can you add the front end markup?

Comment: Is this WinForms?  WebForms?  Something else?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            B1.Text = "LOL";
            Control ctl = FindControl(this, "B1");
            if (ctl is TextBox)
                listBox1.Items.Add(((TextBox)ctl).Text);
        }
        public static Control FindControl(Control parent, string ctlName)
        {
            foreach (Control ctl in parent.Controls)
            {
                if (ctl.Name.Equals(ctlName))
                {
                    return ctl;
                }

                FindControl(ctl, ctlName);
            }
            return null;
        }
```

If you did it like in sample above then all be right.
I suppose you use Windows Froms.
P.S. I can't write a commentary because I haven't 50 reputation.
**Correct Answer**
If TextBoxes are on the FlowLayout then the parent is FlowLayout and you need use the FlowLayout name instead of "this" in line Control ctl = FindControl(this, "B1");. Because "this" it's the MainWindow control.

Comment: Yes, I use Windows Form.

Comment: Put a break point on line where you use the FindControl(Control, String) function. May be it returns null?

Comment: If TextBoxes on the FlowLayuot panel that the compiler does not go into the function, but if TextBoxes only on the form that all right. How to solve this problem?

Comment: If TextBoxes are on the FlowLayout then the parent is FlowLayout and you need use FlowLayout name instead of "this" in line  Control ctl = FindControl(this, "B1");. Because "this" it's the MainWindow control.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the ID property of the Control instance instead. I'm not sure the Name property is available for the Control class, if we are speaking about System.Web.UI namespace.

Answer (score 0):

For WinForms, you'd just do:

```
        Control ctl = this.Controls.Find("B1", true).FirstOrDefault();
        if (ctl != null)
        {
            // use "ctl" directly:
            listBox1.Items.Add(ctl.Text); 

            // or if you need it as a TextBox, then cast first:
            if (ctl is TextBox)
            {
                TextBox tb = (TextBox)ctl;
                // ... do something with "tb" ...
                listBox1.Items.Add(tb.Text);
            }
        }
```

You don't need your own recursive search function...