# C# Form element with VARIABLE name?

Tags: c#, variables

#UPDATE:
i have  C# form, that contain **20 textbox** element.
Is there a way to select those element by using whats called *variable name*.

> Let imagine this scenario:

```
 textBox1.Text="foobar";
 textBox2.Text="foobar";
 textBox3.Text="foobar";
 textBox4.Text="foobar";
 textBox5.Text="foobar";
 textBox6.Text="foobar";
 textBox7.Text="foobar";
 textBox8.Text="foobar";
.....
```

> And i wood Something like this:

```
for(int i=1;i<10;i++){

textBox[i].Text="foobar";

}
```

Comment: See my [previous SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31815750/2330053).  Build up your control name in a String with `"textBox" + i`, then pass that to `Controls.Find()` as in my example.

Comment: I see your code, so thank you vey much for your responce.  but i am wondering if there is another <shorcut> methode to do this.

Comment: @Sean, (Pavel Anikhouski, Sajid);  i have updated my question. is there a possibility to Re-Open it?

Comment: There is, but ONLY if all of those TextBoxes are in the SAME container.  If they are all contained by the Form, for example, you could do: `this.Controls["textBox" + i].Text = "foobar";`.  My other example will find the control "by name" no matter where they are located.

Comment: I already started the process to reopen your question.  Two more people have to vote yes still.

Comment: @Idle_Mind, great job. its work for me. ((this.Controls["textBox" + i].Text = "foobar";)) is exactely what i need. thank you again; how can vote your responce as Useful in this section?

Comment: You can't, not unless the question actually gets re-opened.  No problem.  Have a great day!

Comment: you are welcome teacher!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216647/discussion-between-azimez-and-idle-mind).

Answer (score 0):

I get *response* from **@Idle_Mind**, great job. that ***work for me!***

> ```
> for(int i=1;i<10;i++){
> this.Controls["textBox" + i].Text = "foobar";
> }
> ```

it's ***exactely*** what i need.